# buffer 1024 bits ssh

Tags: python-3.x, socket, ssh

soy nuevo en esto de python y hoy me puse a aprender como imprimir la version de ssh de una pagina web.

Este es el codigo:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
try:
    s.connect(("scanme.nmap.org",22))   
    banner =s.recv(1024)
    print(banner)
except:
    print("ocurrio un error  en la conexion")
```

Alguien me sabria decir porque en la variable banner , que entiendo que es donde se recive el ssh,
se pone un buffer de 1024bits?

porque este numero?
no seria lo mismo si ponemos cualquier otro numero mas o menos alto?

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `socket.recv` recibe como parámetro la cantidad de bytes a leer desde el socket.

El tamaño depende de la aplicación. Por ejemplo, si estás implementando un chat de texto, donde los mensajes son cortos, un buffer de 512 bytes será suficiente.

Por otra parte, si tu aplicación transmite archivos, es mejor un buffer más grande (2-4KB, por ejemplo).

El tamaño del buffer de recepción depende de una combinación de factores de hardware, software, ambientales y de la aplicación, por lo que no hay una regla fija. Sólo queda probar y afinar en terreno.